# Event received in hyperledger composer Node.js SDK very verbose

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am listening for events in a Node.js hyperledger composer client application using the following:

```
listen() {
        LOG.info('Awaiting events');
        this.bizNetworkConnection.on('event', (event) => {
                // event: { "$class": "org.namespace.BasicEvent", "eventId": "0000-0000-0000-000000#0" }
                LOG.info('New Event');
                LOG.info(event);
                let options = {
                    properties: { key:'value'}
                };

        });
    }

I do get notified of an event from a transaction I submitted that emitted an event. However, I cannot make sense of the event output I received. How do I trim this down? Here is a small sample of the event output I receive.
info: [CommodityTrader-App] Hyperledger Composer: Commodity Trading console application
info: [CommodityTrader-App] CommodityRegistry:<init> businessNetworkDefinition obtained tutorial-network@0.0.2
info: [CommodityTrader-App] Awaiting events
info: [CommodityTrader-App] Command completed successfully.

info: [CommodityTrader-App] New Event
info: [CommodityTrader-App]  $ref=$["$modelManager"], external=false, declarations=[type=AssetDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=Asset, classExtension=null, idField=null, type=ClassDeclarationBody, declarations=[], offset=774, line=21, column=25, offset=774, line=21, column=25, abstract=[abstract, undefined], decorators=[type=Decorator, name=docs, type=DecoratorArguments, list=[type=String, value=asset.md, offset=738, line=20, column=7, offset=748, line=20, column=17], offset=737, line=20, column=6, offset=749, line=20, column=18, offset=732, line=20, column=1, offset=749, line=20, column=18], offset=732, line=20, column=1, offset=775, line=21, column=26, $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"], decorators=[$ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][0]["ast"]["decorators"][0], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][0], arguments=[asset.md], name=docs], name=Asset, properties=[], superType=null, superTypeDeclaration=null, idField=null, abstract=true, fqn=org.hyperledger.composer.system.Asset, type=ParticipantDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=Participant, classExtension=null, idField=null, type=ClassDeclarationBody, declarations=[], offset=981, line=28, column=38, offset=981, line=28, column=38, abstract=[abstract, undefined], decorators=[type=Decorator, name=docs, type=DecoratorArguments, list=[type=String, value=participant.md, offset=926, line=27, column=7, offset=942, line=27, column=23], offset=925, line=27, column=6, offset=943, line=27, column=24, offset=920, line=27, column=1, offset=943, line=27, column=24], offset=920, line=27, column=1, offset=982, line=28, column=39, $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"], decorators=[$ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][1]["ast"]["decorators"][0], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][1], arguments=[participant.md], name=docs], name=Participant, properties=[], superType=null, superTypeDeclaration=null, idField=null, abstract=true, fqn=org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant, type=TransactionDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=Transaction, classExtension=null, type=ClassDeclarationBody, declarations=[type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=transactionId, name=String, array=null, regex=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=1377, line=41, column=3, offset=1402, line=42, column=3, type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=timestamp, name=DateTime, array=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=1402, line=42, column=3, offset=1423, line=43, column=1], offset=1377, line=41, column=3, offset=1423, line=43, column=1, type=Identifier, name=transactionId, abstract=[abstract, undefined], decorators=[type=Decorator, name=docs, type=DecoratorArguments, list=[type=String, value=transaction.md, offset=1294, line=39, column=7, offset=1310, line=39, column=23], offset=1293, line=39, column=6, offset=1311, line=39, column=24, offset=1288, line=39, column=1, offset=1311, line=39, column=24], offset=1288, line=39, column=1, offset=1424, line=43, column=2, $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"], decorators=[$ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][2]["ast"]["decorators"][0], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][2], arguments=[transaction.md], name=docs], name=Transaction, properties=[$ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][2]["ast"]["body"]["declarations"][0], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][2], decorators=[], name=transactionId, decorator=null, type=String, array=false, optional=false, validator=null, defaultValue=null, $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][2]["ast"]["body"]["declarations"][1], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][2], decorators=[], name=timestamp, decorator=null, type=DateTime, array=false, optional=false, validator=null, defaultValue=null], superType=null, superTypeDeclaration=null, idField=transactionId, abstract=true, fqn=org.hyperledger.composer.system.Transaction, type=EventDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=Event, classExtension=null, type=ClassDeclarationBody, declarations=[type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=eventId, name=String, array=null, regex=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=1762, line=55, column=3, offset=1781, line=56, column=3, type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=timestamp, name=DateTime, array=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=1781, line=56, column=3, offset=1802, line=57, column=1], offset=1762, line=55, column=3, offset=1802, line=57, column=1, type=Identifier, name=eventId, abstract=[abstract, undefined], decorators=[type=Decorator, name=docs, type=DecoratorArguments, list=[type=String, value=event.md, offset=1703, line=53, column=7, offset=1713, line=53, column=17], offset=1702, line=53, column=6, offset=1714, line=53, column=18, offset=1697, line=53, column=1, offset=1714, line=53, column=18], offset=1697, line=53, column=1, offset=1803, line=57, column=2, $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"], decorators=[$ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][3]["ast"]["decorators"][0], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][3], arguments=[event.md], name=docs], name=Event, properties=[$ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][3]["ast"]["body"]["declarations"][0], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][3], decorators=[], name=eventId, decorator=null, type=String, array=false, optional=false, validator=null, defaultValue=null, $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][3]["ast"]["body"]["declarations"][1], $ref=$["$modelManager"]["modelFiles"]["org.hyperledger.composer.system"]["declarations"][3], decorators=[], name=timestamp, decorator=null, type=DateTime, array=false, optional=false, validator=null, defaultValue=null], superType=null, superTypeDeclaration=null, idField=eventId, abstract=true, fqn=org.hyperledger.composer.system.Event, type=AssetDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=Registry, classExtension=null, type=Identifier, name=registryId, type=ClassDeclarationBody, declarations=[type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=registryId, name=String, array=null, regex=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=2156, line=69, column=3, offset=2178, line=70, column=3, type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=name, name=String, array=null, regex=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=2178, line=70, column=3, offset=2194, line=71, column=3, type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=type, name=String, array=null, regex=null, default=null, optional=null, decorators=[], offset=2194, line=71, column=3, offset=2210, line=72, column=3, type=FieldDeclaration, type=Identifier, name=system, name=Boolean, array=null, default=nul
```

Comment: I should also mention this is for Hyperledger Composer 0.19.3 and Hyperledger Fabric 1.1

Comment: Have you tried the wscat listener as a simple test - described here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/publishing-events
Can you share you event declaration from the model file, and the script where you emit the event?

Comment: wscat listener shows me exactly what I want. event TradeNotification {
  o String eventMessage
    --> Commodity commodity
}    tradeNotification.commodity = trade.commodity;
    tradeNotification.eventMessage = "Commodity assigned to new owner";
    emit(tradeNotification);

Comment: I can also see the event message from my composer client app. It is just that it shows all the  model metadata ahead of the event message which I do not really want/need. Seems like their should be an API to just extract the event message itself, nothing more. But it appears from this example, that your receive all the ModelManager metadata info regardless. https://github.com/aabdulwahed/composer-eventlistner